# Cannot resolve symbol 'AsyncTask' in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, android-asynctask

I have a class which extends AsyncTask in Java, but Android Studio gives an error that the symbol AsyncTask can't be resolved.

```
class GcmRegistrationAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
// CLASS CODE
}
```

Do I miss an import statement or is my code wrong?

Comment: Have you imported this class? `import android.os.AsyncTask`

Comment: If you are using eclipse , press  `Ctrl + Shift + O` , it will auto organize all your import .

Comment: When I do that, I get the same error

Comment: Auto organizing in android studio didnt solve it unforutnately

Comment: Do you build your project with gradle? if so, please post your gradle build file.

Answer (score 9):

I have the same issue in my Android Studio installation. Auto organizing does not work, but if you manually add import android.os.AsyncTask; to your imports, the class will be found.